# Linker error: Unresolved external '__Fastcall_Advgrid::TAdvstringGrid::AutosizeCol......referenced from ...name.OBJ

Tags: c++

I was compiling a project, and this project has a unit called Gamespaceframe, the header file was as follow:

```
:
#include "Advdgrid.hpp"
:
```

and the .cpp was as follow:

```
:
#Pragma link "Advdgrid"
:
```

When I recompiled this project, I got this linker error:

> `Linker error: Unresolved external '__Fastcall_Advgrid::TAdvstringGrid::AutosizeCol(const int, const int) referenced from C:\MHSS\Gamespaceframe.OBJ.`

Any help or comment is appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

David.

Answer (score 0):

That linker error means gamespaceframe.obj made a method call to:

```
__Fastcall_Advgrid::TAdvstringGrid::AutosizeCol(const int, const int)
```

and the linker could not find the above method anywhere. Since it looks like your gamespaceframe.cpp is including "Advdgrid.hpp" and the hpp extension might indicate a template class inside, I would check and make sure that TAdvstringGrid is instantiated properly.